# Force user to complete process of custom portlet page in Liferay(Same as Terms of Use Required page )

Tags: hook, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1.1.ga2 community edition.

I have a custom portlet in which I have insurance application form.

Now using postLogin(login hook) I am able to redirect to this insurance application page once he logs in  .

```
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {

 long usersId = PortalUtil.getUserId(request);
User u=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(usersId);

 Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(u.getCompanyId(),
                        "Not Insured");

 if(!RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole(u.getUserId(),role.getRoleId())){


response.sendRedirect("/group/secure/insuranceForm");

}
}
```

This works fine for me. But suppose if user tries to change the url(entered applications other url)  and hits,  it redirects to that url which should not.

> Means I want to stay user on  insurance application until he completes
>   it. Same feature  that we see  in **password** screen, **reminder**
>   **question** screen or in **agree** **page** when user login first time.

Same thing I want to perform for my insurance application page. How can I  do this? I am using liferay 6.1.1.

I have tried with PortalRequestProcessor.java file made a ext plugin for that.

As we have a protected String processPath(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){} method, I also applied my condition and  tried to to return static string which is nothing but my insurance form page in this way.

```
if (!RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRole(user.getUserId(),roles.getRoleId()) {

                return _PATH_INSURANCE_FORM;
            }



.....

//static variables declaration

private static final String _PATH_PORTAL_LOGOUT = "/portal/logout";
private static final String _PATH_INSURANCE_FORM =
            "/group/app/insurance?insurances=insuranceform";
```

But it shows error as

**Content Encoding Error
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.**

and at the log level it shows :

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-9][RequestProcessor:676] Invalid path was requested /group/app/insurance?insurances=insuranceform
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-9][PortalRequestProcessor:550] User ID 16040

    And at browser console it's showing "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://189.0.25.23:8080/group/app/insurance?insurances=insuranceform"
```

But if I replace return path with existing path like (e.g :_PATH_PORTAL_LOGOUT) then it logouts user properly.

I am also checking at LoginPostAction(login-hook) same condition and redirecting to insurance page.

Is these static string variables declaration place is at different place?

So can anybody tell me how can I overcome from this problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Ran, If you see static variables defined in PortalRequestProcessor are struts path and what you have specified as _PATH_INSURANCE_FORM is some sort of URL. You could create one hook with custom struts action that can redirect user to your jsp in hook. Here you may have to utilize hook and portlet to achieve this.